# LISP - Inspecting a nested List

Tags: tree, common-lisp, nested-lists

Please let me know if I am unclear at any stage. I apologize for not providing code but, given my own lack of knowledge, and lack of material online. I cannot provide any.

I am writing a function which will take a nested list which is based upon a tree-like structure. Where p denotes a parent, and e and f are children.

[image: The tree]

Based upon my own knowledge. I believe that this tree would be represented by the input:

((fe(feef)e)(efee)e(eee(efef)))

What I wish to do is inspect the list, level by level, and represent each e or f  by the 4 e's or f's that compose it.

((fe(feef)e)(efee)**e**(eee(efef)))

((fe(feef)e)(efee)**(eeee)**(eee(efef)))

This would eventually lead to the entire structure being presented like this:

```
((ffff)(eeee)(feef)(eeee) (eeee)(ffff)(eeee)(eeee)
 (eeee)(eeee)(eeee)(eeee) (eeee)(eeee)(eeee)(efef))
```

I will then use flatten to provide a list of all the symbols. This would be the final output.

I understand that it is not good etiquette to questions without example code. But the problem I was given was difficult enough that even working out a method  proved incredibly difficult. If anyone could provide any help, be it code or hints as to how to solve this myself. I would be incredibly grateful.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the 4 e's or f's  that compose it"?

Comment: The overarching problem is an image. Where e and f represent a quadrant of white and black pixels respectively. As I move down the tree I am inspecting an increasingly small quadrant. 1/4 of the image. 1/16 and so on. So an e at say 1/4 of the image. Could be viewed a 4 1/16s.

Comment: It might be represented by the input `((f e (f e e f) e)(e f e e) e (e e e (e f e f)))`. Notice the spaces between the symbols.

Comment: Is that easier to work with? As long as I maintain input that looks relatively similar it is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
(defun expand-tree (tree)
   (labels ((leafp (x)                          ; local function leafp
              (and (consp x)                    ; if x is a cons
                   (= 4 (length x))             ; there are 4 elements in x
                   (every #'symbolp x))))       ; all of which are symbols

     (loop :for e :in tree               ; for every e(lement) in tree
           :nconc                        ; destructively concatenate result of 
           (cond ((symbolp e)            ; if e is a symbol
                  (list (list e e e e))) ; make e ((e e e e))
                 ((leafp e)              ; if e is a leaf
                  (list e))              ; wrap e in a list
                 (t (expand-tree e)))))) ; recurse for e

(expand-tree '((f e (f e e f) e)(e f e e) e (e e e (e f e f))))
; ==> ((f f f f) (e e e e) (f e e f) (e e e e) (e f e e)
;      (e e e e) (e e e e) (e e e e) (e e e e) (e f e f))
```

This doesn't look like the result in the question since `(efee)` looks like a leaf, just like `(feef)` does.

Comment: I think this will be really helpful. Thanks a lot. Could you talk me through it briefly?

Comment: I noticed that the loop is terminating early. For example an e that should return (e e e e)(e e e e)(e e e e)(e e e e) is returning just (e e e e). This is evident with the example where there should be 16 brackets returned but only 10 are.